# Retrofit POST nested object

Tags: kotlin, retrofit2, retrofit2.6

i want to ask a question about using Retrofit 2 POST with Kotlin

this is the input that Postman does

```
"assets": {
       "product": [
            {
                "eTag": "\"a59d9f11f3bfc643b00a96cabb8127a6\"",
                "location": "https---abc.com/abc.png",
                "filename": "abc",
                "type": "PD"
            },
            {
                "eTag": "\"dd74783c22bdb8c7cf5ff0185297ee06\"",
                "location": "https---abc.com/abc.png",
                "filename": "abc",
                "type": "PD"
            }
       ],
       "barcode": [
           {
                "eTag": "\"3a4a0719d5fb9f5a1e4b6b9d246db4de\"",
                "location": "https---abc.com/abc.png",
                "filename": "abc",
                "type": "BC"
            }
       ]
   }
```

this is from my interface

```
    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("create/newassets")
    fun newAssets(
        @Field("assets") assets: Asset? = null,
    ): Call<NewSkuResponse>
```

this is from my class assets

```
data class Asset(

    @field:SerializedName("product")
    var product: MutableList<DataItemAsset?>,

    @field:SerializedName("barcode")
    var barcode: MutableList<DataItemAsset?>
)
```

i got 400 bad request with it, i think my code not working fine
any help, thank you

Comment: What's the error or output that you get when the application crashes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by Oeganz,

It works like a charm with @Body

```
 fun newAssets(
        @Body reqSKU: ReqSKU,
 ): Call<NewSkuResponse>
```

```
data class ReqSKU(
    @SerializedName("assets")
    val assets: Asset
)
```

```
data class Asset(

    @field:SerializedName("product")
    var product: MutableList<DataItemAsset?>,

    @field:SerializedName("barcode")
    var barcode: MutableList<DataItemAsset?>
)
```